# limit text field entry value by length or numeric value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to limit an html5 input field of type number to a range 1-999.99. I tried this, and for some reason it doesn't work.

```
<input id="amount" class="formField" type="number" step="any" style="width:100%" min="1" max="999.99" />
```

But also note, I have the following javascript code that I found out on the net also running on the same field which is designed to give the atm sort of entry feeling.

```
$(function() {
    var input = ""; //holds current input as a string

    $("#amount").keydown(function (e) {
        //handle backspace key
        if (e.keyCode == 8 && input.length > 0) {
            input = input.slice(0, input.length - 1); //remove last digit
            $(this).val(formatNumber(input));
        }
        else {
            var key = getKeyValue(e.keyCode);
            if (key) {
                input += key; //add actual digit to the input string
                $(this).val(formatNumber(input)); //format input string and set the input box value to it
            }
        }
        return false;
    });

    function getKeyValue(keyCode) {
        if (keyCode > 57) { //also check for numpad keys
            keyCode -= 48;
        }
        if (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) {
            return String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
        }
    }

    function formatNumber(input) {
        if (isNaN(parseFloat(input))) {
            return "0.00"; //if the input is invalid just set the value to 0.00
        }
        var num = parseFloat(input);
        return (num / 100).toFixed(2); //move the decimal up to places return a X.00 format
    }
});
```

I was hoping that html5 would solve the problem immediately, but maybe it's conflicting somehow with the javascript? I'm not too advanced with javascript.

Comment: What is _"the atm sort of entry feeling"_ ? _"some reason it doesn't work"_ Can describe details ?

Comment: Sure, and thanks for asking. By atm sort of feeling, it adds the values after the decimal point until there are two values after decimal point, then it keeps pushing existing numbers to the left and new number are added to the right. All I want to do is to not allow the user to input any more values into that field if the value has become greater than 999.99. I can even live with a whole number of 999

Comment: As far as atm style, the whole point is that the user doesn't have to add a decimal point or pay attention to where he puts it.

Answer (score 0):

An HTML5 input max and min doesn't constraint keyboard input, you can check the value in the blur event like:

```
<input id="amount" class="formField" type="number" step="0.01" style="width:100%" min="1" max="999.99" onblur="validate(this);" />
```

Code:

```
function validate(obj)
{
  if(obj.value<1 || obj.value>999.99)
  {
    alert("You have invalid input. Correct it!");
    obj.focus();
  }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0do35p5f/

Comment: Ok, so html5 will not validate with every key press. I get the problem now. But I would prefer to find a way either via html5 or javascript to prevent the  key press from being able to add anything else in the field.

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting `step` attribute to `"0.01"` , using `input` event , `RegExp.prototype.test()` to check value of `input` element , `String.prototype.slice()` to modify displayed value

```js
$("#amount").on("input", function() {
  if (this.value.length > 3 && !/\./.test(this.value)) {
    this.value = this.value.slice(0, 3).concat(".00")
  }      
  if (/\./.test(this.value)) {
    this.value = this.value
    .replace(/(\.\d{2})(?=\d)/, function(m) {
       return m.slice(0, 2)
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input id="amount" class="formField" type="number" step="0.01" min="1" max="999.99" 
style="width:100%"  />
```

Comment: I can see why you did what you did and it should work, but it still doesn't. Weird. Would it be better to parse the value as a float and do a numerical comparison? Would the keypress event returning "false" if the right conditions are not meant prevent the entry of the keypress?

Comment: @user192632 _" and it should work, but it still doesn't."_ ? Can describe details of _"but it still doesn't"_ ? If input , e.g., `5` then use controls to increment , decrement value would be displayed as `5.01` or `4.99` , respectively; maximum value would be `999.99`

Comment: Note, I am not using the arrows on the right to increment the value, they are all key presses

Comment: @user192632 _"not using the arrows on the right to increment the value, they are all key presses"_ Yes. What would be expected result if input `999` ?

Comment: I added your code to the document ready event and I get no failures that the debugger shows me, but it still lets me keep on entering in numbers via the keyboard when it's past it's limit. I ran your code snippet here by pressing "run code snippet", and it's the same thing. Doesn't limit keystrokes if limit has been exceeded..

Comment: @user192632 _"but it still lets me keep on entering in numbers via the keyboard when it's past it's limit. I ran your code snippet here by pressing "run code snippet", and it's the same thing. Doesn't limit keystrokes."_ Not able to reproduce , here. Maximum digits able to input here, before `.` is three , maximum after `.` is two  - total maximum value length is six . Can create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate where more than three digits before `.` , more than two digits after `.` displayed as value ?

Comment: As far as 999 goes, you can't enter that because of the "atm" style of the field. So it would have to be 999.00. But I can still enter in another number to get it over 999, and it should ignore the entered number but it does not.

Comment: Ah, ran your stuff here and I see the problem. I have decimal places and the value always has them because it is pre filled in. As soon as I add a decimal to your input field, I can add all sorts of numbers after the decimal place but if I don't, then it stops at 3

Comment: Here is how the javascript I found makes my field work. This should give you a clearer explanation. http://jsfiddle.net/77bMx/86/

Comment: it works great here, but not with my code. I like what you did, but how could you know if the person wants only one number before the decimal place, or only two? This is why I used the jfiddle solution but it's conflicting somehow with what you are doing.

Comment: I think I know the problem. With the code I got from jsfiddle, after there are more than 2 digits, the additional numbers are not being appended but rather being added to the beginning. So I think the beginning character is what would need to be removed if the value has a length of greater than 6 and no decimal point needs to be checked for because it will always be there. If you could adjust your answer, I think it might work and I can mark it as correct (or fitting of my needs)

Comment: @user192632 _" but how could you know if the person wants only one number before the decimal place, or only two?"_ ? Not certain interpret this portion of comment correctly ? User could input one , two or three numbers before decimal . Did not attempt to incorporate `js` at jsfiddle into solution.

Comment: @user192632 _"So I think the beginning character is what would need to be removed if the value has a length of greater than 6 and no decimal point needs to be checked for because it will always be there. If you could adjust your answer, I think it might work and I can mark it as correct (or fitting of my needs) "_  Value with length greater than six would go beyond requirement initially described at OP _"range 1-999.99"_ ? Not certain which portion of `js` at stacksnippets to adjust ?

Answer (score 0):

HTML number inputs do not constrain keyboard inputs. Therefore, you probably want to use JavaScript to solve this problem.

To add the check of number size to the javascript, you could modify it as follows:

```
$(function() {
    var input = ""; //holds current input as a string

    $("#amount").keydown(function (e) {
        //handle backspace key
        if (e.keyCode == 8 && input.length > 0) {
            input = input.slice(0, input.length - 1); //remove last digit
            $(this).val(formatNumber(input));
        }
        else {
            var key = getKeyValue(e.keyCode);
            if (key && parseFloat(input + key) <= 99999) {
                input += key; //add actual digit to the input string
                $(this).val(formatNumber(input)); //format input string and set the input box value to it
            }
        }
        return false;
    });

    function getKeyValue(keyCode) {
        if (keyCode > 57) { //also check for numpad keys
            keyCode -= 48;
        }
        if (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) {
            return String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
        }
    }

    function formatNumber(input) {
        if (isNaN(parseFloat(input))) {
            return "0.00"; //if the input is invalid just set the value to 0.00
        }
        var num = parseFloat(input);
        return (num / 100).toFixed(2); //move the decimal up to places return a X.00 format
    }
});
```